# mingw compiled executable does not output characters in powershell/cmd

Tags: c++, powershell, mingw-w64

I tried to use the following code to output files in current directory

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::filesystem;

int main() {
    for (directory_iterator next("."), end; next != end; ++next) {
        std::cout << next->path() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the compile command is a simple `g++ demo.cpp -o demo.exe`, the path to g++ is `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe`.

It worked properly when i ran it in bash (msys2),

```bash
$ ./demo.exe
".\\.clangd"
".\\.vscode"
".\\demo.cpp"
".\\demo.exe"
```

but when i did the same thing in powershell or cmd, it output nothing.

```
PS C:\Users\cnjawi> .\demo.exe
PS C:\Users\cnjawi>
```

The following code could run just fine in powershell and cmd.

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::filesystem;

int main() {
    std::cout << "test\n";
    return 0;
}
```

However, if i add the original code, the issue occurs, even the "test" couldn't be output.

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::filesystem;

int main() {
    std::cout << "test\n";
    for (directory_iterator next("."), end; next != end; ++next) {
        std::cout << next->path() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you search entire drive for the file.  Results may be going to a different folder than expected folder.

Comment: Try running the failing program by double-clicking it in the explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to HolyBlackCat's comment. When i double-clicked this program, Windows prompted `The procedure entry point ~ could not be located`, which gave the key info -- the program doesn't actually work in powershell due to some missing DLLs, rather than working but not outputting.

However, a collapsed program does not issue warnings in powershell, which made it appear to have worked "normally".

The simplest way to solve it is using the static library. For this instance, use `g++ -c demo.cpp` to generate demo.o and then `g++ -static demo.o /ucrt64/lib/libstdc++fs.a -o demo.exe`(in bash).

Answer (score 0):

The bin directory of your chosen [MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) should be added to your System Path variable in a suitable position.

For example, if you are using the `UCRT64` environment and MSYS2 is installed in the default location, you would add `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin` to your System Path variable.

I added my entry in the System Path variable after the main `C:\WINDOWS` entries. Add it too low in the list and it doesn't work.

Comment: Or copy the dlls next to the executable. You'll need to do that to distribute the binary to others anyway.

Comment: It isn't obvious which dlls are required. Maybe there is a straight forward way of finding out but I don't know.

Comment: Run `ntldd -R my_app.exe`. Out of the dlls it lists, ignore anything not in the `bin` directory.